# UserManager's CreateAsync method doesn't work (Identity)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

My Post method

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register()
        {
            User user = new User { Email = "asfa@gmail.com", UserName = "asfa@gmail.com" };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "SS22!faasd");
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // install cookie
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    //how can i see my errors here
                }
            }
            return Ok();
        }
```

I am trying to create user with UserManager and CreateAsync method, but it doesn't work. In postman I always get `200 OK`.

`UserManager` is connected to my database, because I can get my users with get method.

Also I dont have any cshtml files, so I cant output errors on page.

Comment: does your `CreateAsync` method calls `Complete()` method after creating the user?

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan I think no, what is it?

Comment: it may be connected to your data context, which you use to save the data.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan It is connected, because I can get users using `_userManager.Users.ToList()`

Comment: Would you please update your post with the code indicating what is doing `_userManager.CreateAsync`  method internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find error, I return `OK(result)`, and see this error in postman.

Answer (score 1):

> In postman I always get 200 OK.

You are always getting `200 OK` because at the end of a method you are returning `OK()` method.

In order to have some other status messages consider checking if the user is created and only then return `OK()` method otherwise either throw an exception, like this:

```cs
throw new ArgumentException("Wasn't able to add user")
```

or return some [HTTPError](http://Exception%20Handling%20in%20ASP.NET), like this:

```cs
 return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Not able to create user");
```

Note: you can also throw an exception if the user already exists when you try to add a new user.

---

> I am trying to create user with UserManager and CreateAsync method, but it doesn't work.

This is connected with your `_userManager.CreateAsync` methods logic. Please revisit it.